# Bootstrap 3.3.6 - How to show/hide multiple elements via Nav Tabs on a single page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Within Bootstrap 3.3.6, I get how nav tab and tab content regions work.  For every tab you click on, a relational content area will will display itself. But in my special case I am working with a 2 column layout that has nav tabs in one column, and an additional private list of links in another column called "private-list".

The demo can be viewed here

http://www.bootply.com/NJXUfgD5iE

When I click on my Section 2 nav tab, my section 2 content regions displays as it should with Bootstrap 3.  But how can I also tell my .private-list, located in my left column to only show when I click my Section 2 and 3 tab, and then hide again, when I click Section 1?

For instance, is there a class process (rather than an ID process) I can use to lock in multiple boostrap component elements to a single nav tab click?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have your own click handler for the tabs:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
  if($(this).attr("href") != "#tab1"){
     $(".public-list").hide();
     $(".private-list").show();
  }
  else{
     $(".public-list").show();
     $(".private-list").hide();
  }
})
```